# How to read from a file descriptor on Android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I have the following code on C++:

```
char* utf8 = "clips/file.h264"
int fd = AAsset_openFileDescriptor(AAssetManager_open(AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetMgr), utf8, 0),&outStart, &outLen);
```

Now that I have this **file descriptor**, how can I **read** it in Android? Normally I'd use AMediaExtractor for .mp4 files, but it's a raw byte file, no formats, just raw NAL units. I want to feed it directly to AMediaCodec decoder myself.

Comment: Android is based on Linux, which is a POSIX compatible system, i.e. it's Unix-like. There are plenty of tutorials and books available about reading files using file-descriptors on Unix-like system all over.

Comment: I don't know about android, but have you tried the `read` function?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs have you looked at [`AAsset_read()`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/asset#aasset_read) yet? You already have an `AAsset*` from [`AAssetManager_open()`](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/asset#aassetmanager_open), so there is no need to use `AAsset_openFileDescriptor()` for low-level reading if `AAsset_read()` can get the data for you